# How to disable Developer and Web Searches in Spotlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Yesterday I upgraded to Lion and it seems it got some additions on Spotlight - the Developer and Web Searches groups.

Sadly I couldn't find a way to disable them. There isn't an option in the Spotlight preferences and I couldn't find the right `defaults` option.

Any ideas on how to hide them? They are cluttering Spotlight FAR too much :)

Comment: FYI, this is still happening at the age of Catalina :( Dummy Xcode.app solution still works :) Homebrew now reports "Xcode is not installed/outdated" :*

Comment: At this time, still only a partial solution is provided (for Developer). Another question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300352/enable-spotlight-web-search) suggests there may be or have once upon a time been a terminal command recipe to disable Web Search results in Spotlight, but I've not yet seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I detailed a fix in this forum thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1193533

Comment: This only works for removing the Developer category.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! The community appreciates answers that are more than just a link. It's okay to have al ink in your answers, but you must also summarize it in the answer itself. The idea is to make the answer able to stand on its own. Thanks!

Comment: Further explanation about Nathan's comment: what if the site you linked to goes down?... So will you please the text of your solution here as well?

Answer (score 36):

Spotlight thinks you are a 'Developer', if you have Xcode installed, or happened to install it at any time in the past, and hence shows you search results that maybe relevant to a developer.

When Xcode is actually installed and present on the computer, a check-box called 'Developer' appears in the `System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results` panel giving us the option to disable 'Developer' results from appearing in our searches. When Xcode is not detected, the check-box disappears from the Preferences Panel, but Spotlight continues to show results from the 'Developer' category.

I am currently on Yosemite, and had installed and un-installed Xcode way back on Mountain-Lion or Lion, opting to use the 'Command Line Tools' instead. I also had Spotlight disabled until recently, and started getting hundreds of Search Results under the Developer category, once I re-enabled it. The clutter was making spotlight unusable.

Unable to find a solution anywhere on the Web, this is what I finally tried, and it worked:

I created an empty file called `Xcode.app` in the Applications folder, and the missing 'Developer' check-box showed up in Spotlight Preferences, which I could then un-check to solve my problem.

Open `Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app` then type and press Enter after each of the following lines to create the dummy Xcode app

```
cd /Applications
touch Xcode.app
```

then head to Spotlight Preferences and uncheck 'Developer' (you might need to restart the System Preferences app to see the missing check-box appear).

Notes:

- You need to keep the dummy `Xcode.app` even after changing the
  setting, deleting it will cause the setting to revert back.
- Another solution would be to install Xcode itself

Comment: As noted, you have to keep the dummy `Xcode.app`, however you can **hide the dummy Xcode.app** file by executing `chflags hidden /Applications/Xcode.app` from the Terminal. Thanks to  https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/spotlight-developer-and-web-searches-cant-be-disabled.1193533/#post-22001562

Comment: on mojave i no longer have to leave the Xcode.app dummy file. create the file, open spotlight settings and disable Developer, remove Xcode.app. developer no longer shows up

Comment: @vampiire Only as long as you don't open the Spotlight settings in the System Settings. If you open the settings again after you deleted the Xcode.app, it will reset and enable the Developer results in Spotlight search again. Still does so even on macOS 14 Sonoma.

Answer (score 7):

*As the top answer is a link to a forum post, below is the steps from post in case it disappears one day.*

The fix below describes how to remove the spotlight developer category without installing XCode first.

Convert the plist to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist
```

Open the file in the editor of your choice:

```
vim ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist
```

Just before `</array>` at the bottom, add the following:

```
<dict>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>SOURCE</string>
</dict>
```

Convert the file back to binary:

```
plutil -convert binary1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist
```

Log out and back in again.

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thanks for posting this solution directly here, instead of linking to the forum.

Comment: This did not work for me (macOS Ventura). I seemed to make those changes successfully as described. I even checked if the changes were really made by converting the plist file back to XML again. When I logged out and back in, the changes to the plist file were gone and somehow my Spotlight search results settings had become ineffective. I had to rebuild Spotlight indices and redo all Spotlight settings for things to get back to normal and had to find another way to make Spotlight not show the "developer" files in search results.

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution I could find, block all spotlight web access using little snitch. I guess this is up there with iCloud helping itself to your personal files.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Developer' search results are enabled by default but the toggle to disable them is only visible if Xcode is installed. This seems to be a long-standing bug confirmed to happen on clean installs up to macOS 14 Sonoma.

The 'Developer' search results can be disabled by adding an entry to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist` using the following command.

```
defaults write com.apple.spotlight orderedItems -array-add '{ "name" = "SOURCE"; "enabled" = 0; }'
```

However, as long as Xcode doesn't exist, opening 'Spotlight & Siri' settings in System Settings resets and enables it again. To prevent accidental reset, it may be preferable to add a dummy Xcode app using this command.

```
touch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

This makes the toggle for 'Developer' search results in 'Spotlight & Siri' in System Settings visible anyways, so one might prefer to disable it in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Tried that, still getting those results. How do I trigger reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

Although the Search Results do not have toggles to sort or suppress these results, it's trivial to add the folders to the Privacy Pane.

Perhaps something like this might work to Suppress the Developer hits?
[image]

I don't see an obvious way to suppress the Web Search yet, but thankfully it's placed last as a catch all - last resort. I'll probably feedback / bug Apple if 10.7.1 doesn't address that with a preference.

Comment: Well this means that I have to exclude my whole HD... :(

Comment: I've tried to get a flood of developer results but can't. It only contributes one, two or three hits to the bottom of the list spotlight window. What are you seeing and how could the developer files be anywhere but the developer folder?

Comment: As a web developer myself, I have a projects folder in my home dir. Every project have more than enough files in it and it just fills the spotlight results with items I do not want there. Not that it gets in my way or anything, I still get the results I'm looking for at the top, but it still annoys me to have them there.

Comment: Certainly file a bug - they added a class to the tool, it needs to be orderable/filterable like all the other categories of data.