# enable spotlight web search

Tags: spotlight

a couple os versions back I disabled spotlight's web search with a terminal command and now I'd like to undo that but I can't figure out how to do that. Is there a way to undo or return spotlight to default settings?

Comment: specifically I deleted or disabled something that enabled spotlight to access the internet to the point where simply resetting spotlight does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset Spotlight to default settings by deleting the preference file at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist` and logging out and back in.

Comment: I think that i deleted whatever allows spotlight to access the web so resetting default settings didn't work.